# Looking for a good interactive pdf viewer

Tags: software-rec, pdf

I like zathura for its simple UI, very nice for just reading.
I like xournal for its rich annotation features.

But what I still need is a reader that

- is interactive,
- has a "find" feature,
- is able to highlight an copy text to clipboard,
- is independant of any desktop environments (gnome, kde ...) and
- is able to display simple notes e.g. made with xournal (so no epdfview).

Is there such a viewer?

Comment: Except for the notes feature `xpdf` would be sufficient.

Comment: `evince` will do all that too, except probably not the xournal notes unless you save them in a portable format.  I doubt there is any software that will work with xournal's native format except xournal -- it's just too obscure for other people to support.

Comment: I really like evince but it is gnome-dependant. I will take a look at xpdf.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r evince isn't dependent on any desktop environment. Very few applications are. An application may use this or that widget library which is also used by a desktop environment, but you can mix applications using different widget libraries to your liking.

Comment: [Look](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/evince) ... 4 necessary dependencies and one optional to gnome packages. Well xpdf isnt thaaaat convenient :D. I am looking for a independant evince equivalent for easy work purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this IS zathura. Meanwhile I switched to arch. Now I have an up-to-date version of it. xournal for noting, zathura for everything else.

zathura is just beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview), a lightweight tabbed document viewer. It's Qt-based and DE-independent.

You can find qpdfview in the default Ubuntu and Debian repos. More recent versions are available from the following PPAs:

- [release versions](https://launchpad.net/~b-eltzner/+archive/qpdfview)
- [daily builds](https://code.launchpad.net/~adamreichold/+archive/qpdfview-dailydeb)
- [experimental builds for Ubuntu 12.04 with backported poppler](https://launchpad.net/~b-eltzner/+archive/qpdfview-exp)